# The default controller for extension and plugin can not be determined ERROR in TYPO3

Tags: php, typo3

I built an extension and I would like to add plugin options at the time of adding the plugin to the page

```
 Extension Name : hotels
```

in Hotel model ,

```
 <?php
    class Hotel{
          ... get set methods ...
      }
  ?>
```

in HotelController.php

```
 <?php
  namespace TYPO3\Hotels\Controller; 

   class HotelController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController{

    public function listAction(){
      //    $this->view->assign('result', array('test' => 'hello, u r in list'));               }
   }
 ?>
```

in ext_localconf.php

```
 \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'TYPO3.' . $_EXTKEY,
    'hotels',
     array('Hotel' => 'list,single,display,update,save,preview,edit')
    );
```

in ext_tables.php

```
  \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
    $_EXTKEY,
    'hotels',
   'list of Hotels'
   );

 $pluginSignature = str_replace('_','',$_EXTKEY) . '_hotels';

 $TCA['tt_content']['types']['list']['subtypes_addlist'][$pluginSignature] ='pi_flexform';

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPiFlexFormValue($pluginSignature, 'FILE:EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/Configuration/FlexForms/flexform_myhotel.xml');
```

Somehow, I think i'm missing something. This gives an error :

I can see the option in backend side at time of adding extension but when i want to show (view) that Page where I add that extension , generates an error .

```
----> The default controller for extension "Hotels" and plugin "hotels" can not be determined. Please check for TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin() in your ext_localconf.php.
```

Please Guide me

Comment: tried to reinstall extension, add plugin and clear TYPO3 cache?

Comment: hey Christoph ..!!
not working yet..!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In TYPO3 6.x, you are advised to use namespaced classes and tell the `configurePlugin` method your vendor name.

As you didnt include any of your controller code, I'll try to sketch it:

1. At first, make sure, you use a namespaced controller class-remember to set a Vendor name.
2. Make sure, your actions are named with the `*Action` suffix

**EXT: myext/Classes/Controller/HotelController**

```
namespace MyVendor\MyExt\Controller;
class HotelController {
    /**
    * @return void
    */
     public function listAction(){
     }
}
```

Next, mention the namespace in configurePlugin like this:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'MyVendor.' . $_EXTKEY,
    // UpperCamelCase please, refer to [1]
    'Hotels',
     array('Hotel' => 'list,single,display,update,save,preview,edit')
);
```

This allows the class locator to resolve the classes correctly.

To verify it, make sure you re-install your extension.

PS: Please use the namespaced classes whenever possible in 6.x. The old `Tx_*` classes are only aliases and put additional load on your interpreter.

[1 - TYPO3 API Docs for ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin()](http://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_utility_1_1_extension_utility.html#a62ddcf2fe79e88f82de935cb1ff64e23)

**Update:**

There is a multitude of possible errors.

1. You wired a FlexForm. Did you set the `switchableControllerActions` appropriately?
2. One thing I saw more than once: The `f:link.action` (or f:uri.action respectively) doesnt like to be without an appropriate `controller` attribute
3. You clearly missed the namespace concept :) Rename your ControllerClass to `HotelController` and the file must live in `Classes/Controller/HotelController.php`, then do the adjustments to `configurePlugin()` to reflect the vendorName as I described

Comment: hey Cedric Thnks for giving answer..
but not yet working..display same error..!!

Comment: Can you please tell us your namespace and other contents of the files in question? A gist would be fantastic.

Comment: You missed the namespace thing completely, please follow my instructions. Tx_* Classes and Namespaces conflict.

Comment: What we also experienced is that entirely removing the plugin and creating the plugin again solves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

in ext_localconf.php

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'TYPO3.' . $_EXTKEY,
    'hotels',
    array(
        'Hotel' => 'list,single,display,update,save,preview,edit'
    ),
    // non-cacheable actions
    array(
        'Hotel' => 'list',
    )
);
```

in ext_tables.php

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
    $_EXTKEY,
    'hotels',
    'list of Hotels'
);

$extensionName  = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::underscoredToUpperCamelCase($_EXTKEY);
$pluginSignature = strtolower($extensionName). '_hotels';


if (TYPO3_MODE === 'BE') {

    /**
     * Registers a Backend Module
     */
    \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerModule(
        'TYPO3.' . $_EXTKEY,
        'web',   // Make module a submodule of 'web'
        'hotels',   // Submodule key
        '',                     // Position
        array(
            'Hotel' => 'list,single,display,update,save,preview,edit'
        ),
        array(
            'access' => 'user,group',
            'icon'   => 'EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/ext_icon.gif',
            'labels' => 'LLL:EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_hotels.xlf',
        )
    );

}

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addStaticFile($_EXTKEY, 'Configuration/TypoScript', 'Hotels List');
```

@Clear cache and remove typo3temp data

Comment: Which version of TYPO3? and developed with extension_builder?

Comment: version : TYPO3 6.1 & this hotel extension developed by myself not using extension_builder ..
I tried with extension_builder but giving me the same error..