# Default controller of 2nd plugin in extension can not be determined

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I made an *extbase* extension with *extension builder* in TYPO3 6.2 and so far I have one working frontend plugin. But now I want to add another plugin that can use the same Classes of that extension and I can't even successfully add it.

When clicking on the page that should show my new plugin I receive this error:

> Caught exception: The default controller for extension ...
>   and plugin "Stats" can not be determined. Please check for
>   TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin() in your
>   ext_localconf.php.

This is what I did previously:
After adding a new plugin "Stats" in the extension builder I see following code in my ext_localconf.php:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'CC.' . $_EXTKEY,
    'Appoints',
    array(
        'Appointment' => 'list, show, new, create, edit',
        'Feedback' => 'new, create, list',

    ),
    // non-cacheable actions
    array(
        'Appointment' => 'list, show, new, create, edit',
        'Feedback' => 'new, create, list',

    )
);

\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'CC.' . $_EXTKEY,
    'Stats',
    array(
        'Appointment' => 'statistic',

    ),
    // non-cacheable actions
    array(
        'Appointment' => 'statistic',

    )
);
```

And in ext_tables.php I got:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
    'CC.' . $_EXTKEY,
    'Appoints',
    'Appointments'
);

\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
    'CC.' . $_EXTKEY,
    'Stats',
    'Statstics'
);
```

It seems the extension builder did everything perfectly.

In my AppointmentController.php
(which is correctly namespaced - `namespace Vendor\Extname\Controller;`) I added:

```
    public function statisticAction() {
        echo "testing";
    }
```

Then I added the new plugin to my page in the backend. (Please ignore the spelling error in the picture I already corrected it but it wasn't the cause of my problem)
        [image]

So what could be the reason? And how can I solve this the easiest way?
Should I type something into the `switchableControllerActions` in extension builder since I'm using the same controller with both plugins but different actions? If so - what?

> EDIT: I found out it must have something to do with my backend page, idk what - but if I change the plugin on the same page it works,...I'm searching for the causing differences between the two pages that might cause this...

Comment: Have you cleared the TYPO3 configuration cache?

Comment: Please, check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22160671/2070270 Maybe, you can find some hints there

Comment: just do extension uninstall/install once, because some time this error comes because of typo3 cache.

Comment: Seems like a Cache problem to me, too. Flush the typo3temp/Cache/Code/cache_core/ext_localconf*.php for the changes in your ext_localconf.php to take effect.

Comment: I flushed all 3 Caches and uninstalled/installed the extension multiple times already - but I will do it again since it seems nothing else is wrong - maybe I didn't reload the webpage at the right times...

Comment: code looks good. BTW no need to reinstall the extension. If you want to purge all caches at once, use the button in the install tool "clear all caches".

Comment: and you guys are sure there's nothing wrong with using the same controller with both plugins? I thought this might cause the problem.

Comment: @Cold_Class Nope. Same controller is no problem. I got multiple extension with the same scenario. Could you try inserting another blank content element and retrace your steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like everyone in the comments stated all I did was correct and should've worked...
I noticed that my plugins worked on one backend page but didn't work on another.
As I couldn't find any differences between those two pages that caused this I deleted both of them and created two new ones inserting one plugin into each page.

Now it works...so my solution if you encounter a similar problem:
Before trying to dig too deep into the cause just try to delete a problematic backend page and create a new one. Maybe it can solve the problem, it did it for me.

Comment: Yup. The configuration for your pluign is stored in tt_content.pi_flexform. But it doesn't store key references, but the actual values themselves. If you change the flexform, the configuration breaks.

Comment: I don't actually understand what a flexform is...are these the standard backend forms with whom one can add content and change options like access of usergroups to a page? I tried to understand this explanation but it already failed at the first noun "Grid Element", no idea what element they're talking about: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/gridelements/Chapters/Flexform/Index.html

Answer (score 0):

You made a typo in your ext_localconf.php when you declared your second plugin,

```
    "Stats": \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'CC.' . $_EXTKEY,
    'Stats',
    array(
        'Appointment' => 'statistic', ==> 'Statistics' => 'statistic'

    ),
    // non-cacheable actions
    array(
        'Appointment' => 'statistic', ==> 'Statistics' => 'statistic'

    )
);
```

because "Statistics" is the right controller name for that plugin if you called it "StatisticsController".

Comment: But I only have one controller, I want both plugins to use the same controller called "AppointmentController", isn't that possible??