# TYPO3 ajax The default controller for extension and plugin can not be determined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, typo3

I have TYPO3 7.6.18 and I trying ajax on front end and I get error 'The default controller for extension \"fefiles\" and plugin \"piphoto\" can not be determined'.

setup.txt

```
ajaxCall = PAGE
ajaxCall {
   typeNum = 22222
   config {
    disableAllHeaderCode = 1
    xhtml_cleaning = 0
    admPanel = 0
    additionalHeaders = Content-type: text/plain
    no_cache = 1
    debug = 0
   }
   10 = USER
   10 {
        userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
        extensionName = fefiles
        pluginName = Piphoto
        vendorName = Istar
        controller = Photo
        action = ajaxHandler
   }
}
```

ext_tables.php

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
    $_EXTKEY,
    'Piphoto',
    'Upload Photo'
);
```

js

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".send-photo-comment").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "?id=0&type=22222",
            data: {},
            success: function(msg){
                console.log(msg);
            }
        });
    })
})
```

ext_localconf

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'Istar.' . $_EXTKEY,
    'Piphoto',
    [
        'Photo' => 'list, ajaxHandler, show, new, create, edit, update, delete',
    ],
    // non-cacheable actions
    [
        'Photo' => 'list, ajaxHandler, show, new, create, edit, update, delete',
    ]
);

Help me please)
```

Comment: Probably you missed the VENDOR in method `registerPlugin` ext_tables.php file:

`\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
            'VEDOR.Extensionkey',
            'Pi1',
            'Extension Display Name'
);`

Comment: No, I am did't missed it. I checked it right now. I still have error - The controller \"Photo\" is not allowed by this plugin.

Comment: A very similar entry is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146726/the-default-controller-for-extension-and-plugin-can-not-be-determined-error-in-t

Comment: Just if anybody needs it: Make sure that you do not use `switchableControllerActions` which is deprecated since TYPO3 10.

Answer (score 1):

How does your `ext_localconf.php` look like?
Should include something like:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'Istar.' . $_EXTKEY,
    'Piphoto,
    array(
        'Photo' => 'ajaxhandler'
    )
);
```

Comment: \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'Istar.' . $_EXTKEY,
    'Piphoto',
    [
        'Photo' => 'list, ajaxHandler, show, new, create, edit, update, delete',
    ],
    // non-cacheable actions
    [
        'Photo' => 'list, ajaxHandler, show, new, create, edit, update, delete',
    ]
);

Answer (score 0):

This basically means that you need to define a controller in your ext_localconf.php. Usually the first entry is taken as default controller/action. Here's an example:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
  'YourVendor.' . $_EXTKEY,

  // Plugin name
  'Pi1',

  // An array of controller-action combinations. The first one found is the default one.
  array(
    'YourController' => 'index,new,create,edit,update'
  ),

  // An array of non-cachable controller-action-combinations (they must already be enabled)
  array(                
    'YourController' => 'new,create,edit,update'
  )
);
```

Comment: Try to add the action in the ajax-url

Comment: I tried url: "?id=0&type=22222&action=ajaxHandler",   still same error ((

Comment: You need to add the action this way: tx_myExtension_myPlugin[action]=new

Comment: Thank you very much! I guess do it myself 
?id=0&type=22222&tx_fefiles_piphoto[controller]=photo&tx_fefiles_piphoto[action]=ajaxHandler

But I get the same error (((

Comment: new error The controller \"photo\" is not allowed by this plugin.

Comment: You need to allow it in the array `[ 'Photo' => 'list, photo, ajaxHandler, show, new, create, edit, update, delete', ]`

Comment: Already allow ( you can see in my post. Stupid typo3...( I don't know how fix it

Comment: I don't see the action. Only the Controller name `Photo`. Try adding it to the commasepareted list

Comment: \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'Istar.' . $_EXTKEY,
    'Piphoto',
    [
        'Photo' => 'list, ajaxHandler, show, new, create, edit, update, delete',
    ],
    // non-cacheable actions
    [
        'Photo' => 'list, ajaxHandler, show, new, create, edit, update, delete',
    ]
);

That what I have

Comment: upper case or lower case?

Comment: Show me your url of the ajax call

Comment: url: "?id=0&type=22222&tx_fefiles_piphoto[controller]=photo&tx_fefiles_piphoto[action]=ajaxHandler",

Comment: Try "?id=0&type=22222&tx_fefiles_piphoto[controller]=Photo&tx_fe‌​files_piphoto[action‌​]=ajaxHandler"